# Incorporating knowledge of aggregate outcomes to constrain predictions on finer scales

Tags: bayesian, multilevel-analysis, boosting, maximum-entropy

I've got county-level longitudinal data on the timing of an event between the years 1998 and 2012, and I want to use it to form a predictive model for the time that that event will occur in future years, given features of those years.

Now, I've got state-level data on the (median) time of the event between 1979 and the present.  I've also got county-level covariates (but not outcomes) between 1979-1997 and 2013-present.

If I take county-level predictions for the periods 1979-1997 and 2013-present, aggregate them to the state level and compare them to the known state-level aggregates, I find that that my predictions are biased downwards, both in the early and later periods.  In other words, I'm consistently predicting that the event will come before it does.

Intuitively, I should be able to use the state-level known outcomes to constrain the model.  One way to do this would simply be to impute the missing county-level values for 1979-1997 and 2013-present with their state-level values.  But I fear that this will distort the model in ways that are hard to predict.

Are there more sophisticated approaches to this problem?  Is this a use-case for something explicitly bayesian?  I'm also reminded of applications of maximum entropy/information theory that I've seen used in ecology.  But I'm not sure how to proceed.

For more context, the predictive model is `xgboost` with fairly shallow trees as the base learner.  I've got about 1000 features and about 50K observations.